# How do you log on as a different VNC user in Linux?

Tags: vnc

Regardless of whether I use TightVNC viewer or RealVNC viewer to logon to my linux RaspberryPi, I am unable to move any windows I create.

I've tried to grab the top bar of the window in order to move it but the cursor does not change and I cannot drag the window anywhere.  I am also unable to resize the window either.

I am wondering whether this is because I am logged on as a specific user?  Whether I use TightVNC or RealVNC, I don't get prompted for a user, only a password.

By the looks of this, the user is determined by the VNC server end.  I have TightVNC installed on the RaspberryPi and it is running Kali Linux.

Where can I choose which user I log on as when using VNC?

Comment: there is maybe an option in tightVNC or realVNC called "view-only"

Comment: @EJL yes I wondered this but I cannot find any configuration settings at the server end which supports read-only.  I have since found out that if I open a file manager window, I can move this around; the title bar is a different colour.  Still cannot resize it though.  Interesting that one window can be moved but not resized but all others (that I have found so far) cannot be moved...

Comment: realvnc and tightvnc are clients, maybe check your VNC server